# Problemas cuando quiero guardar datos remotos en un List con Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

estoy creando un DialogFragment con radious options en Android. Las opciones del DialogFragment son obtenidas de forma remota a través de un servidor, mediante Volley. Estas opciones son guardadas en  un List. 
Cuando llamo a este metodo `Acciones.attendancesPlayerToGame(gameID, getContext(),players)`, que internamente funciona perfectamente, nunca actualiza mi List players, ya que el tamaño de players siempre me vale cero.

**MyDialogFragment**

```
  public AlertDialog createRadioListDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    String gameID= getArguments().getString("gameID");

    List<JugadorView> players=new ArrayList<JugadorView>();
    Acciones.attendancesPlayerToGame(gameID, getContext(),players);
    final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[players.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i< players.size();i ++){
        String nombre= players.get(i).nombre;
        String apellidos = players.get(i).apellidos;
        String nombreComplet = nombre + " " + apellidos;
        items[i] = nombreComplet;
    }



more code
    }
```

Cuando pongo un breakpoint dentro del metodo `Acciones.attendancesPlayerToGame`, internamente ala List player se le van añadiendo los elementos, pero despues en la clase MyDialogFragment la list player nunca se actualiza.

**attendancesPlayerToGame**

```
public static void attendancesPlayerToGame(final String idGame,final Context context, final List<JugadorView> jugadorViewList) {
    final String URLLISTGROUP = "http://www.myweb.com/app/file.php";
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLLISTGROUP,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                            String emailJugador = jsonObject.getString("emailJugador");
                            String nombreJugador = jsonObject.getString("nombreJugador");
                            String apellidosJugador = jsonObject.getString("apellidosJugador");
                            String jugadorId = jsonObject.getStri

ng("jugadorID");


                                JugadorView jugadorView = new JugadorView(nombreJugador, apellidosJugador, emailJugador, jugadorId);

                                jugadorViewList.add(jugadorView);



                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("idGame", idGame);

                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por su respuesta.